# calling different method of one spring controller

Tags: spring-mvc

In my controller there are different method i want to call them with one form action. i dont know how to map map the request to particular method with different value of submit button , as i  run my index page it directly go to controller from their it can render the view from `view()` of my controller and as the `Search .jsp` is open i get the by default `0` value on my `EmployeeId` input field i dont know why its happening plz help me out i m new on spring

here is my controller

```
   package com.nousinfo.tutorial.controllers;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.nousinfo.tutorial.model.EmployeeForm;
import com.nousinfo.tutorial.service.impl.EmployeeServiceImpl;
import com.nousinfo.tutorial.service.model.EmployeeBO;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/search")
public class SearchEmployeeController {

    private EmployeeServiceImpl employeeServiceImpl;

    public void setEmployeeServiceImpl(EmployeeServiceImpl employeeServiceImpl) {
        this.employeeServiceImpl = employeeServiceImpl;
    }



    @RequestMapping(value = "/searchspring", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView view(
            @ModelAttribute("employeeForm") EmployeeForm employeeForm)
            throws Exception {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("employeeForm", employeeForm);
        model.setViewName("Search");

        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/employeeNo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView searchByEmpNo(
            @ModelAttribute("employeeForm") EmployeeForm employeeForm)
            throws Exception {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("employeeForm", employeeForm);
        Long i = employeeForm.getEmployeeNumber();

        EmployeeBO employeeBO = employeeServiceImpl.getEmployee(i);
        System.out.println(employeeBO);
        model.addObject("employeeBO", employeeBO);

        model.setViewName("EmployeeDetail");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/empByName", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView searchByEmployeeName(
            @ModelAttribute("employeeForm") EmployeeForm employeeForm) {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("employeeForm", employeeForm);
        List<EmployeeBO> employeeBOs = employeeServiceImpl
                .findEmployees(employeeForm.getFirstName());
        model.addObject("listEmployeeBO", employeeBOs);
        model.setViewName("EmployeeList");
        return model;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/empByDeptId", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView searchByDeptId(
            @ModelAttribute("employeeForm") EmployeeForm employeeForm) {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("employeeForm", employeeForm);
        List<EmployeeBO> employeeBOs = employeeServiceImpl
                .getAllEmployeeByDeptid(employeeForm.getDepartmentId());
        model.addObject("listEmployeeBO", employeeBOs);
        model.setViewName("EmployeeList");

        return model;

    }

}
```

and this is my index.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%  
response.sendRedirect("/EmployeeWebSpring/search/searchspring");
%>
```

this is my search.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<fmt:setBundle basename="ApplicationResources" />
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Employee Search Page</title>

</head>
<body>
    <form:form action="/EmployeeWebSpring/search/empByName"  commandName="employeeForm" method="post">
        <table border="0">



            <tr>
                <td>Employee_ID</td>
                <td><form:input path="employeeNumber"  /></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="method" value="FindById" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Employee_Name</td>
                <td><form:input path="firstName" /></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="method" value="FindByName" /></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>Employee_Name</td>
                <td><form:input path="departmentId" /></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="method" value="FindByDeptNO" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><font size=3>For
                        Searching the employees by<b>Employee Name</b><br />you can use %
                        match all the records with the given pattern
                </font><br /> <font size="2"> <i>e.g <b> for search by</b>EmployeeName<br />
                            matches alL the employees whose name starts with character <b>S</b></i></font></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to configuring different endpoints for the same form based on the button clicked (using either separate forms in the HTML or changing the form action via JS), you could use the `params` attribute of the `RequestMapping` annotation to further narrow the form submission to a specific controller method based on the value of the button (or any other form submitted field).  See the [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-params-and-headers) on this for more detail.

Using this strategy, your request mappings would look something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/employeeSearch", method = RequestMethod.POST, params="method=FindByName")
public ModelAndView searchByEmployeeName(
        @ModelAttribute("employeeForm") EmployeeForm employeeForm) {
...

@RequestMapping(value = "/employeeSearch", method = RequestMethod.POST, params="method=FindByDeptNO")
public ModelAndView searchByDeptId(
        @ModelAttribute("employeeForm") EmployeeForm employeeForm) {
...

@RequestMapping(value = "/employeeSearch", method = RequestMethod.POST, params="method=FindById")
public ModelAndView searchByEmpNo(
        @ModelAttribute("employeeForm") EmployeeForm employeeForm)
        throws Exception {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

> i dont know how to map map the request to particular method with different value of submit button

Have each search in a separate form. Each form mapped to different controller methods. Like this:

```
<form:form action="empById" method="post" commandName="searchBean">
    Employee_ID
    <form:input path="employeeNumber"  />
    <input type="submit" name="method" value="FindById" />
</form:form>
<form:form action="empByName" method="post" commandName="searchBean">
    Employee_Name
    <form:input path="firstName" />
    <input type="submit" name="method" value="FindByName" />
</form:form>
<form:form action="empByDeptNo" method="post" commandName="searchBean">
    Employee_Name
    <form:input path="departmentId" />
    <input type="submit" name="method" value="FindByDeptNO" />
</form:form>
```

Now different search requests will map to the correct controller method.

> i get the by default 0 value on my EmployeeId input field i dont know why its happening

Before you add an instance of EmployeeForm to the model, initialize it to what ever default value you would like to have seen in the search page.

Comment: rather than providing multiple form action i have change the action value through javascript